# ASC2 compiler with Flash Builder 4.6

Tags: apache-flex, air, flash-builder, asc2

I have downloaded the latest AIR SDK and compiler from here:
http://www.adobe.com/devnet/air/air-sdk-download.html
But Flash Builder 4.6 doesn't accept it saying it's not a Flex SDK.

Is there a way to persuade Flash Builder 4.6 to use the ASC2 compiler? I am currently using the Apache Flex SDK 4.14.1 which seems not to include the latest compiler. [I even overlaid](https://helpx.adobe.com/x-productkb/multi/how-overlay-air-sdk-flex-sdk.html) the AIR SDK on the Flex one but to no avail.

Comment: Did you click the big orange "Download Now" button?  If so, that's the problem -- you need to use the fine-print/plain-text links near the bottom of the page.

Comment: But it says that the plain text link does not include the asc2 compiler, which is what I am looking for.

Comment: Why?  The asc2 compiler isn't designed for compatibility with FB.

Comment: @Brian The new compiler is supposedly better, so it's natural to want to use it with my IDE. Maybe there's a batch file that at least automates the job of compiling an existing FB project with ASC 2?

Comment: Look in Flash Builder's Preferences > Flash Builder > Installed AIR SDK and find the path to the existing AIR location.  Inside that folder, which version of AIR does "AIR SDK Readme.txt" mention?

Comment: @Brian It doesn't say "Installed AIR SDK", but only "Installed Flex SDKs". I have the latest Apache Flex: 4.14.1 FP17.0 AIR17.0. But that doesn't contain the ASC2. I guess I will have to build a custom batch command file to automatically build my FB project with the new compiler

Comment: Good luck.  I'm pretty sure what you're trying to do just isn't supported by Adobe.